# How to append tfoot in gridview in asp.net (Web form)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, webforms

How to perform same code on asp.net Grid-view in asp.net  I want to use `datatable` on `asp.net Grid-View` .I faced many problems when i convert it to asp.net Grid-View. Can anybody help me?

This code is working correctly but i want to use this on `asp.net grid view`. How to use this?

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

        <style>
            tfoot {
                display: table-header-group;
            }
        </style>
        <table name="item" id="item" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script>
            // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
            $('#item tfoot th').each(function () {
                var title = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
            });

            // DataTable
            var otable = $('#item').DataTable();

            // Apply the search
            otable.columns().every(function () {

                var that = this;
                $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function () {
                    if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                        that
                            .search(this.value)
                            .draw();
                    }
                });
            });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RowDataBound event to generate the `thead` and `tfoot` tags.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        e.Row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"`. But this code just adds the thead and tfoot to a html table.

Comment: yeah its working now but it add <tfoot><tr><td> not add <th>